# Dynamically loading react component from prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load a react component with several subcomponents (that themselves have props) dynamically, similar to the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952448/dynamic-loading-of-react-components).

I've built a `Base` component that takes a string value, and then the Base component looks up that string value to instantiate the sub-components that need to be rendered. At the moment I've only added a single component for "Users" to illustrate the problem.

However, I keep running into an error saying that

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I think everything is being imported correctly and webstorm doesn't show any issues with what I've done, until I load the page.

[I've built a stackblitz to show the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cqwiuu?file=Base.tsx,UserGrid.tsx,UserForm.tsx,App.tsx). It seems like this route is very straightforward, but I'm missing something and I don't see what it is.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `E2J`, but it looks like `PaneDirective` expects `content` to be a function that returns a JSX element - not a JSX element directly (https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/splitter/getting-started). 

So replacing `content={<ResourceGrid setGridRef={setGridRef} rowSelected={rowSelected} />}` with `content={() => (<ResourceGrid setGridRef={setGridRef} rowSelected={rowSelected} />)}` leads to a different set of errors in `UserGrid.tsx`. For example, `empTemplate is not defined` - which looks reasonable because it is not defined in `UserGrid.tsx`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also everything compiles and executes fine if `UserGrid` is replaced with a custom dummy component, so I think your dynamic loading should work fine after adding a wrapper function and there's a separate unrelated issue with `UserGrid`.